# PHP Apache Linux expose files top php but not apache

Tags: php, html, linux, apache, permissions

Im trying to learn some php and have set up a simple website that copies a file to the website root directory when a user visits using a php script.

The directory structure is
/webroot/
/webroot/filesStorage/Dummyfile.txt

I do not want the files in the fileStorage directory to be exposed to the web if i put in the url http://MyUrl.example/filesStorage/Dummyfile.txt

but both apache and php are running as www-data user, so if I restrict the files or directory from www-data user then the files are not exposed but also php cannot copy them to the /webroot/directory.

I have used php and nginx before and they run as different users so this is easy to set permissions on the /fileStorage directory so php can access but apache cannot.

is there something im missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out .htaccess file is the way to do this!